# Main can not call a function: function was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c

I am in the process of changing a C file to a C++ file (to eventually integrate it with a C program). I'm very new to C++ and in fact this is my first exposure to it. I have a test.cpp file that declares function main and hello as follows:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    hello ();
    return 0;
}

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello there!" << endl;
}
```

The test.h file is declared as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void hello();
```

When I compile the program using g++ test.cpp, I get the error "hello was not declared in this scope".

Any suggestions?

Also, where does one find the API for C++ classes and their functions?

Comment: What is the command you have fired?

Comment: So if a C program, say myprog.c, needs to invoke the function hello(), I would declare that function in myprog.h as extern "C" void hello?

Comment: Calling C++ from C is hard, at least harder that calling C from C++. Best to put all functions that don't require c++ in a separate `.c` source file, so you compile them as C, and declare them extern "C" from your C++ source files. Put some #ifdef __CPLUSPLUS around the "extern C" in .h files so you can include them from both languages; check the standard include files for examples.

Comment: Thank you for a complete compilable test case but can you please post the full text of the actual error that you are getting?

Comment: -1 The code in your question does not match the error message

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may have misread the error message. The only mistake that should cause an error is the fact that you haven't qualified `endl` with `std::`. Are you sure that the error message wasn't about `endl`?

Compiling your complete test case, I get the following:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘void hello()’:
test.cpp:11:37: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
      std::cout << "Hello there!" << endl;
                                     ^
test.cpp:11:37: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from test.h:1,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:564:5: note:   ‘std::endl’
     endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
     ^
```

Fixing the error by adding the `std::` to `endl` fixes all compile and link errors and gives `hello` C language linkage as expected.

(Note, there is no harm - and it's probably even clearer - to add `extern "C"` to the definition of the function `hello`, but it is not necessary so long as the first visible declaration declares the correct language linkage.)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `extern "C"` altogether,
Use the standard namespace.

But if you must compile the function as `extern "C"`, it is not required you put it before the function definition, only the declaration, which you have done.

But if you'd like to add it to both declaration and definition, it would be fine for you to do so.

Example:

```
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    hello ();
    return 0;
}

void hello()
{
    cout << "Hello there!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: well, he did that in the include file.

Comment: External is not the problem; it's in the c++ source file, so it will be compiled to have a c++ signature; but the include file implies a c signature.

Comment: So if I remove the keyword extern "C" and if a C program, say myprog.c, needs to invoke the function hello(), I would declare hello in myprog.h as extern "C" void hello?

Comment: @DavidOtano The program in your answer compiles with identical meaning if you remove `extern "C"`. So, what exactly are you claiming in your answer?

Comment: You are wrong. As Charles pointed out, and as I said in my previous comment, the program in your answer compiles with identical meaning if you remove `extern "C"`. So, again, what are you claiming in your answer.

Comment: @DavidOtano Your claim is demonstrably false. Please remove the `extern "C"` from the definition of the function, and observe the successful compilation. You should delete this erroneous answer.

Comment: @DavidOtano The first sentence of your answer is manifestly and demonstrably wrong.

Comment: @DavidOtano You are not listening to us. Take your program, the code in your answer. Remove `extern "C"` from the definition of the function. Then observe that the code compiles. Then read your first sentence and realise that what you said is wrong.

Comment: @David Also, please stop getting confused between declaration and definition. The declaration of the function, in this example, is in the header file. The definition is in the .cpp file. I've edited your answer twice now to correct that. Please don't edit it back.

Comment: If you know that, what is your answer claiming. You should remove the erroneous first sentence then. Or at least edit it so that it is factually accurate. Really though you should delete your answer and upvote Charles answer. Since he's the person that is really making sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're declaring it `extern "C"` in the include file, but it's in the hello.cpp source file, so it will get compiled as c++, not c.

Comment: This is false. the definition doesn't change the language linkage of `hello`, it remains with C language linkage as first declared. The original declaration is visible at the point of definition.